# How do I select statistically significant points from the set of points?

Tags: java, statistics

Server is receiving a certain rate(12 per minute) of monitoring data for some process via external source(web services, etc). Now process may run for a minute(or less than) or for an hour or a day. At the end of the process, I may be having 5 or 720 or 17280 data points. This data is being gathered for more than 40 parameters and stored into the database for future display via web. Imagine more than 1000 processes are running and the amount of data generated. I have to stick to RDBMS(MySQL specifically). Therefore, I want to process the data and decrease the amount the data by selecting only statistically significant points before storing the data to the database. The ultimate objective is to plot these data points over a graph where Y-axis will be time and X-axis will be represented by some parameter(part of data point).

I do not want to miss any significant fluctuation or nature but at the same time I cannot manage to plot all of the data points(in case the number is huge > 100).

Please note that I am aware of basic statistical terms like mean, standard deviation, etc.

Comment: Try [Googling for "outlier detection methods"](https://www.google.co.uk/#newwindow=1&q=outlier+detection+methods) to get some ideas.

Comment: @RogerRowland ..I am on it..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If this is a constant process, you could plot the mean (should be a flat line) and any points that exceeded a certain threshold. Three standard deviations might be a good threshold to start with, then see whether it gives you the information you need.

If it's not a constant process, you need to figure out how it *should* be varying with time and do a similar thing: plot the points that substantially vary from your expectation at that point in time.

That should give you a pretty clean graph while still communicating the important information.

Comment: It is a totally unpredictable process. However, it will have some minima and maxima, both local(over slice of an interval) and global. It may be monotonically increasing or decreasing or wavy sort of curve.  By the way what do you mean by "Three deviations". Please explain.

Comment: Three standard deviations: a standard deviation is a measure of variability about a mean. You can expect to find about 65% of your data points within +/- one sigma (standard deviation) of your mean. About 95% within +/- two sigma, and about 98% within +/- three sigma. (And maybe 3 out of a million at six sigma.)

Comment: But this general approach can only work if you know where you expect the data to be. If it's totally unpredictable, we'll have to figure out something else.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect your process to be noisy, then doing some [smoothing through a spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothing_spline) can help you reduce noise and compress your data (since to draw a spline you need only a few points, where "few" is arbitrary picked by you, depending on how much detail you want to get rid of).

However, if your process is not noisy, ***then outliers are very important***, since they may represent errors or exceptional conditions. In this case, you are better off getting rid of the points that are close to the average (say less than 1 standard deviation), and keeping those that are far.

**A little note:** the term "statistically significant", describes a high enough level of certainty to discard the null hypothesis. I don't think it applies to your problem.